# unisong7e is missing from the map file?

Tags: dvi, texlive-2016, evince

On ubuntu 16.04, I use latex to compile a tex file but the evince(3.18.2) can't view the dvi file with some font problem like [image: this,] , and the terminal's prompt is `mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for unisong7e. mktexpk: perhaps unisong7e is missing from the map file.` How do I resolve this problem? The test.tex is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\begin{document}
\title{文章标题}
\author{张力}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\section{第一部分}
这是第一部分内容。
\subsection{第一子部分}
这是第一子部分内容。也支持繁體字，漢語，國家。
\end{document}
```

and use `evince test.dvi` to view it. Maybe all kinds of Chinese fonts is not supported, and it will occur the same problem such as `unihei missing` or `unikai missing`.
Further, I xelatex to compile and the pdf file is OK with evince viewing.

Comment: As far as I can see, TeX Live only has the metrics for `unisong`. Can you please add a simple example of code producing the issue?